Address Autocomplete in LWC
I implemented  lightning input address with  show-address-lookup = true on my community page, and it was working perfectly two days ago. Now, the search bar isn't showing only the address fields are showing.  What could be the issue?
Below is my Code
HTML
<lightning-input-address
    address-label='Address'
    street-label='Street'
    city-label='City'
    country-label='Country'
    province-label='State/ Province'
    postal-code-label='Zip/ Postal Code'
    onchange={addressInputChange}
    show-address-lookup>
    </lightning-input-address>

Note: Maps and Location Settings are enabled


Seeing the below error message in the console log
Refused to frame 'https://maps.a.forceusercontent.com/' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "frame-src 'self' https://service.force.com/embeddedservice/ https://cs333.salesforce.com https://sfdc-link-preview-staging.sfdc.sh https://sfdc-link-preview.hk.salesforce.com https://cdn.embedly.com https://www.youtube.com https://player.vimeo.com https://play.vidyard.com https://player.cloudinary.com https://fast.wistia.net https://players.brightcove.net https://s1.adis.ws https://scormanywhere.secure.force.com https://appiniummastertrial.secure.force.com https://js.stripe.com/ https://www.paypal.com https://www.sandbox.paypal.com https://checkoutshopper-live.adyen.com/ https://checkoutshopper-test.adyen.com/ https://pal-test.adyen.com https://www.google.com/recaptcha/ https://www.gstatic.com/recaptcha/ https://pay.google.com https://*.b.forceusercontent.com/lightningmaps/ https://*.b.forceusercontent.com https://test-location.force.com https://merzcommunities--quality.sandbox.file.force.com https://merz-quality2.oktapreview.com https://socialtool.m3rzd3v.com https://merz-quality2-admin.oktapreview.com https://merz-public.okta-emea.com https://www.googletagmanager.com https://*.osano.com https://iframe.pagbrasil.com https://sandbox.pagbrasil.com https://api.cquotient.com https://nescara.com https://www.nescara.com https://cert-xiecomm.paymetric.com https://xiecomm.paymetric.com https://xipayapi.paymetric.com https://merzcommunities--quality--c.sandbox.vf.force.com *.force.com https://siteintercept.qualtrics.com https://*.qualtrics.com https://analytics.google.com https://s3.walkmeusercontent.com walkme.wixanswers.com frog.wix.com fonts.googleapis.com nr-data.net fonts.gstatic.com https://*.walkme.com https://*.onetrust.com https://util.appinium.com https://api.appinium.com https://content.appinium.com https://az766683.vo.msecnd.net https://appiniumcontentcentralus.blob.core.windows.net https://appiniumcontenteastaus.blob.core.windows.net https://appiniumcontentwesteu.blob.core.windows.net https://upload.appinium.com https://merz-oce.s3.amazonaws.com https://merz-oce.s3.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com https://brandbox.m3rzd3v.com https://merzaestheticsbrandbox.com". 

Does this work if you run this as Sys Admin outside of communities?

Didn't check that but that will work I guess, Something weird happening, ANything after update on winter 25

Try disabling Lightning Web Security from Session Settings under Setup and then check if it works?

It's already disabled attached screenshot

Issue Resolved!
After adding the Trusted URL Details in my ORG it got Resolved!
Setup--> Quick Find --> Trusted URLs
Thanks to Hemanth for Giving hint about the security.

